# Noarchivelog mode in logical standby

Tags: oracle

We are having one Logical standby for reporting purpose. Due to space issue I am planning to change the logical to NOARCHIVELOG mode. If i do that what will be the impact on the logical side.

I havent try anything yet. Before trying anything i am expecting some advice from the experts.